# jq: output values of ids instead of numbers

Tags: json, jq

Here's my input json:

```
{
    "channels": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Pop"},
        { "id": 2, "name": "Rock"}
    ],
    "links": [
        { "id": 2, "streams": [ {"url": "http://example.com/rock"} ] },
        { "id": 1, "streams": [ {"url": "http://example.com/pop"} ] }        
    ]
}
```

This is what I want as an output:

```
"http://example.com/pop"
"Pop"
"http://example.com/rock"
"Rock"
```

So I need jq to replace `.channels[].id` with `.links[].streams[0].url` based on `.links[].id`

I don't know if it's right, but this is how I managed to output the urls:

```
(.channels[].id | tostring) as $ids | [.links[]] | map({(.id | tostring): .streams[0].url}) | add as $urls | $urls[$ids]

"http://example.com/pop"
"http://example.com/rock"
```

The question is, how do I add `.channels[].name` to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sometimes have to be careful what you ask for, but this will produce the result you said you want:

```
.channels[] as $channel
| $channel.name,
  (.links[] | select(.id == $channel.id) | .streams[0].url)
```

Output for the given input:

```
"Pop"
"http://example.com/pop"
"Rock"
"http://example.com/rock"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **reduce** and **setpath** to make a `$urls` lookup table from `.links` and then scans `.channels` generating corresponding urls and names.

```
  (
    reduce .links[] as $l (
      {};
      setpath([ $l.id|tostring ]; [$l.streams[].url])
    )
  ) as $urls
| .channels[]
| $urls[ .id|tostring ][], .name
```

If multiple urls are present in the "streams" attribute this will
print them all before printing the name.  e.g. if the input is

```
{
    "channels": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Pop"},
        { "id": 2, "name": "Rock"}
    ],
    "links": [
        { "id": 2, "streams": [ {"url": "http://example.com/rock"},
                                {"url": "http://example.com/hardrock"} ] },
        { "id": 1, "streams": [ {"url": "http://example.com/pop"} ] }        
    ]
}
```

the output will be

```
"http://example.com/pop"
"Pop"
"http://example.com/rock"
"http://example.com/hardrock"
"Rock"
```